# Метод mailto не работает в СМС

Tags: html, веб-программирование, email, uri

Система работы такая: на телефон приходит СМС, содержащая следующий код:

```
<a href=mailto:username@gmail.com?subject=Заявка%20выполнена&body=#154785>
```

При нажатии на ссылку должно формироваться исходящее письмо с получателем, темой и содержанием, но при открытии службы Gmail заполняется только получатель, 
а поля "тема" и "содержание" пустые. Что не так?

Comment: А если экранировать кириллицу?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, они до сих пор не исправили 100 летний баг.

[groups.google.com](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msgid/gmail/0fac71fe-546f-4dba-a85c-93c28ac1bbc6%40googleproductforums.com)